# LyX math. git and maths mode

Tags: math-mode, lyx, amsmath, lyx-layouts, gitinfo

1. It's probably a pretty trivial question but where do I find or download  git for LyX?
2. Where can I find details on LyX math? I presume it's distinct from maths mode, i.e. ctrl m, where the math's box comes up and the code is in blue, come up (within the LyX document in blue font). I presume that this corresponds to the greyed out math's code or format

where you can enter commands to use and install packages layouts 
like \sloppy?
I almost every where on this site. It looks a lot easier to use. If anyone knows how I access that mode, that would be much appreciated.

3. I presume that **math's** mode is another name **ctrl +m** (math's editor mode, and Lyx max, ie the math-x box wherein you can a panel is displayed below and maths commands are automatically rendered.) which creates a new math's box, or is this something distinct again ?

   4. I presume that math's editor mode is likewise another name for this entity.

Is there a way of inserting text into math's mode into a math box without having to manually put a use the command  **\,** to insert a space, after every word, one at a time, in math's mode, or commands such  **\text,** **\mathcal** .

I presume there is no package or automatic command that will render this automatic?

5. Is there any easier way to having flowing text that is does not overflow the margins particular in **math's mode.**
6. In the math's **inline multi-equation environment** is there way to add additional columns so that I add text along the rhs to explain each line. I notice that I cannot add additional columns, only rows Unlike in '**insert cases'** or '**insert matrix'**. for example

[image: mult-line,environment,no,ability,to,columns, only rows,]

Comment: This question has multiple questions. Please see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246328/362591) for your future posts.

Comment: LyX user guide has a very detailed section on the math operations (Section 5 of version 2.2.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no special Git for LyX. Git and LyX are separate, but LyX can communicate with Git. This is covered in Help > Additional.

   You can call certain Git functions from within LyX. However, to take full advantage if Git, you should learn command-line approach. Also, graphical programs such as SourceTree helps you visualize the process.
2. You can find details about LyX math in Help > Math.

2.5 You can insert LaTeX commands with ERT (Insert > ERT box). Read the help for more information.

3. Yes ctrl + m puts you into math mode in LyX.
4. Yes.

4.5 Yes, do an additional ctrl + m and you can insert a text box within math.

5. Please create a new, specific question, along with a minimal example .lyx file. Surely there is a way.
6. If LyX supports adding columns in a context (e.g. table, math array, matrix), it will be available in the toolbar that shows when you enter that environment.

Comment: thanks for this (i presume then insert ert box is the same thing or somehow related to the use packing, add commands, \centering, start documenet, end documents blocks of lyx code i see everywhere on this site?

Comment: I would have thought that lyx would or would not does it depend on the layout and the packages installed. Do you which layouts do support in lyx . Ill add an example

Comment: Add a small info on Git...

Answer (score 0):

about "6-" you can used \tag and \tag* like:

1- Ctrl+m then:

```
a=b+c\tag*
```

2- then click space then write any thing after the equation.